# a priori grounds of mathematics

Tags: foundations, mathematical-philosophy

Hi,

from the title of the question you may guess I'm new to the site, and I am. Even though I've read the FAQ and I know that this isn't the place for such open questions (I believe it is open, but my knowledge isn't very wide), what I need are some references, does anyone have any papers on the a priori grounds of math? my question goes towards the origin, not its legitimacy (but papers on the later would also be apreciated, are there?).

A better way to formulate the question or approach the subject would be welcome as well.

PS: please excuse my english, I hope it is understandable at the very least.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain your question more clearly? Are you asking what are the most fundamental or universal axioms of mathematics? Of course there is a rich literature on this topic. But in its current form, unfortunately,  your question is likely to be closed for lack of focus.

Comment: Dear Mónica, foundations of mathematics and mathematical philosophy are two very broad areas that deal with such matters (and a few more). I closed your question because it is not specific enough.

Comment: hold on please, before closing it, could you give me some references? some papers I can read about the issue?
What I want is to know a bit of the discusion that is currently held on the issue.

Comment: how a priori is math? how much is taken from experience? was Kant right?

Comment: Mónica, you will (probably) have better luck at http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree that this question doesn't belong on MO.  However, I think that the intended question is this.  Kant argued that mathematical truths are "synthetic a priori."  Mónica seems to be asking for an introduction to the literature on Kant's philosophy of mathematics.